# wordpress, where is the code for the contact page?

Tags: php, wordpress

Which page in wordpress has the code for the contact page?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress does not come with a contact page. You either have to code one yourself or download a plugin.

Comment: Do you have the reference for doing that (write the code, not plugin) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plugin: [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/)

Also, this question is not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Form 7 is great.

and you could also check the Tiny Contact Form plugin (note: it uses tables).

or use Google Docs' form or use Wufoo which allows you to easy embed to other sites.